# How to show all the commits in git logs since creation of local repository?

Tags: git, merge, version-control

I merged a branch(let's say 'origin') with another one(let's say 'merge') yesterday but then I saw all my recents commits in log of 'merge' were of 'origin'. How do I get all the commits of since repository creation?

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you mean. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `git log --all` to-get history of any other branche combined with yours?

If it does not work please post the commands you issued to better assist you.